# Select elements missing in serialize form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, find

In submit function I try to filter hidden field from serialize form and then compare current data with previously saved data. If data is the same user should see the message. One problem that I have is with select form elements. For some reason select form element is not included in serialize form data. I have tested and if I do not use `.find()` then I see select form element. Is there a reason why select is not included in  one case and it is in the other?

```js
var frmOriginalData;

$('.frm-Submit').on('submit', submitAdminFrm);

function submitAdminFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
  var frmID = e.currentTarget.id,
    recID = $('#frm_recordid').val(),
    frmCurrentData = $("#" + frmID).find("input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();

  console.log(recID + '\n' + frmCurrentData + '\n' + frmOriginalData);

  if (recID && frmCurrentData == frmOriginalData) {
    alert('Nothing changed on the form.');
  } else {
    frmOriginalData = $("#" + frmID + " input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();
  }
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control no-serialize" name="frm_recordid" id="frm_recordid" value="34">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-info">Active:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control is-staff" name="frm_active" id="frm_active" required>
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing `$("#" + frmID)` to get the form, when `e.target` is already the form element?

Comment: @Taplar In my code I have to use form ID in few other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the `select` because you're **specifically** looking for `input` elements:

```
frmCurrentData = $("#" + frmID).find("input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();
// -----------------------------------^
```

`select` elements aren't `input` elements.

You could use jQuery's pseudo-class [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) instead:

```
frmCurrentData = $("#" + frmID).find(":input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();
// -----------------------------------^
```

Example:

```js
var frmOriginalData;

$('.frm-Submit').on('submit', submitAdminFrm);

function submitAdminFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
  var frmID = e.currentTarget.id,
    recID = $('#frm_recordid').val(),
    frmCurrentData = $("#" + frmID).find(":input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();

  console.log(recID + '\n' + frmCurrentData + '\n' + frmOriginalData);

  if (recID && frmCurrentData == frmOriginalData) {
    alert('Nothing changed on the form.');
  } else {
    frmOriginalData = $("#" + frmID + " input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();
  }
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control no-serialize" name="frm_recordid" id="frm_recordid" value="34">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-info">Active:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control is-staff" name="frm_active" id="frm_active" required>
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

`:input` matches `input`, `select`, `textarea`, and `button` elements.

---

**Side note 1**: You don't put quotes around the sub-selector in a `:not()` pseudo-class. E.g.:

```
frmCurrentData = $("#" + frmID).find(":input:not('.no-serialize')").serialize();
// Remove these quotes --------------------------^-------------^
```

---

**Side note 2**: You **already** have the `form` element in `e.currentTarget` (and also `this`, btw), so there's no need to get its `id` and then look it up again:

```
frmID = e.currentTarget.id
// ...
frmCurrentData = $("#" + frmID).find(...)
```

Instead, just use what you already have:

```
frmCurrentData = $(e.currentTarget).find(...
// or
frmCurrentData = $(this).find(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only selecting `input` elements: `.find("input:not('.no-serialize')")`.  You need to do:

```
.find("input:not('.no-serialize'), select:not('.no-serialize')")
```

or

```
.find('input, select').not('.no-serialize')
```

or

```
.find(':input').not('.no-serialize')
```

But note that with `:input`, the jQuery docs recommend:

> To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input").